# Trouble with matching bool values

Tags: f#

I am not very proficient in F#, but I have to find out why one of two pieces of code does not work.
The first one checks, if a file exists and then, if it does streams it, this one works.
The second one only checks, if a file exists with the same function and returns an error, if it doesn't, this one doesn't seem to be working, even though it uses the same function.

File stream working:

```
                let pdfmaybe = 
                    ctx.GetService<IConfiguration>()
                    |> getBasePath
                    |> getFileName clId theDoc
                    |> getDocument
                match pdfmaybe with
                | Some pdf -> 
                    do! ...
```

File exists check, not working, always returns 404:

```
                let fileExists = 
                    ctx.GetService<IConfiguration>()
                    |> getBasePath
                    |> getFileName clId theDoc
                    |> doesFileExist
                match fileExists with
                | true ->
                    return! setStatusCode 200 next ctx
                | false -> 
                    return! setStatusCode 404 next ctx
```

Code for file exists and getDocument:

```
let doesFileExist fileName : bool = 
    fileName
       |> File.Exists

let getDocument fileName : Option<FileStream> = 
    if (fileName |> doesFileExist) then
    Some (fileName |> File.OpenRead)
else
    None
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, it turned out we have some very old middleware that changes the formatting for the later request and it is case sensitive.

Comment: It's no problem. I'm happy to hear you were able to solve your problem, and appreciate you reporting that. Given that this solution is unlikely to help future readers, I'm going to vote to close this question—that way, when people are searching for a problem with similar keywords, other questions which are more likely to be relevant to their issues are prioritized. (The question may or may not get closed, but if it does I wanted to explain why so it's not a surprise.)